# Kotlin REPL giving strange answer to arithmetic operation

Tags: kotlin

As part of learning Kotlin, I was getting familiar with REPL.
Doing that I found something strange when I do `2 + 2.001`

It works fine with other decimal values.

```
2 + 2.0
>4.0

2 + 2.01
>4.01

2 + 2.001
>4.0009999999999994      <-------------Super strange         

2 + 2.0001
>4.0001
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?